# SVG animation slow on mobile - inherent to SVG, or implementation problem?

Tags: css, performance, animation, svg, frontend

I've got an animation on my site that uses a couple of SVGs, some CSS 3D transforms, and a bit of JS-driven animation.

This works fine on desktop, but on mobile (Android Firefox, Chrome) there's a significant FPS drop. The performance issues are noticable when scrolling, and when the zoom animation is triggered once the date picker has been used.

www.zachogan.com/curiosityhome

I've tried to simplify the SVGs down by reducing the number of paths and the complexity of each path, but with no luck.

Is this an inherent issue with SVGs, or am I just implementing this wrong?

Comment: Drawing paths is simple. What costs performance-wise are operations that need to be repeated for every pixel for every frame: filters, partial transparency and gradients all imply extra steps for compositing and blending multiple layers. Hardware support in the form of memory for framebuffers and parallel floating point computation may be available on desktop processors, but could be absent on low-energy mobile systems.

Comment: You're doing some fairly expensive operations -- in particular, a matrix transform for tilting the land mass and a gradient fill, which also has transforms. What would help is to bake those transforms into the base paths. Photopea can convert all the points to new values. You should also consider rasterizing the land mass as a high resolution PNG. Your paths have a LOT of points, and you're putting a lot of work on the 2D engine. At a certain point, it becomes a trade-off in rendering performance vs file-size and image quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zombiedoctor's comment helped me to resolve this:

> You're doing some fairly expensive operations -- in particular, a matrix transform for tilting the land mass and a gradient fill, which also has transforms. What would help is to bake those transforms into the base paths. Photopea can convert all the points to new values. You should also consider rasterizing the land mass as a high resolution PNG. Your paths have a LOT of points, and you're putting a lot of work on the 2D engine. At a certain point, it becomes a trade-off in rendering performance vs file-size and image quality.